# Autofilter criteria value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a table with activated autofilter mode and it is known that only Criteria1-type filtering is applicable (i.e. items of interest are implicitly indicated). My goal is to extract a criteria list for each column in VBA. I used `IsArray(.Filters(i).Criteria1)` to determine if there is more than 1 item selected for a particular column and everything works fine when either 1 or more than 2 items are selected. However, when I select 2 items, `.Filters(i).Criteria1` is not recognized as an array for some reason. `.Filters(i).Criteria1` returns only the item that is higher in the list.

Could anyone explain me: why is it so and what is the best way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Criteria1 will only return the first visible item displayed, not the full array.

Comment: This is not correct. If you select 3 or more items, Criteria1 is an array that consists of all selected items. However, for some reason it  does not work for 2 selected items.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old as question, but in case anyone ends up confused here, confused.

With the a filters object (part of the worksheet.autofilter.filters collection probably)

Here is 1 happens:

**1 filter on a column:**

`filters(i).criteria1` is a string

**2 filters on a column:**

`filters(i).criteria1` is a string

`filters(i).criteria2` is a string

**3 or more filters on a column:**

`filters(i).criteria1` is an array of strings (which is a variant)

`filters(i).criteria2` doesn't exist

This isn't that clear from MSDN, but it's what happens.  My only guess is that in past versions of excel it wasn't possible to add more than 1 filter criteria, and so the old criteria1 and criteria2 types were maintained for backwards compatibility.  Still though, it's a stupid system.

Which means that the only way to get the filter properties (as far as I can see) is as follows:

```
For Each f In ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Filters
    If f.On Then
        If IsArray(f.Criteria1) Then
            cA = f.Criteria1
        Else
            c1 = f.Criteria1
            On Error Resume Next
                c2 = f.Criteria2
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Because Criteria2 errors for both `IsEmpty(f.Criteria1)` and `IsNull(f.Criteria1)` so as far as I can see the only way to check if it exists is with an ugly `on error resume next`